# #include inside function body or reduce its visibility

Tags: c++

Is there a way to reduce the scope of `#include` directive?

I mean for example to do something like this

```
void functionOneDirective()
{
    #include "firstInstructionSet.h"
    registerObject();

    // cannot access instantiate()
}

void functionSecondDirective()
{
    #include "secondInstructionSet.h"
    instantiate();

    // cannot access registerObject()
}

void main()
{
    //cannot access instantiate() && registerObject()
}
```

Comment: `#include` is essentially what it says *include the contents of that named file* **here**. So yes, your code works and dumps the contents of the included header into the function body. I still recommend against it.

Comment: What `#include` does (more or less) is a copy-paste operation. The content of the included file replaces the `#include` line.

Comment: @GhostCat ok, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to restrict "includes" to a subset of the using file. It is always visible for anything following the include.

If you are interested in providing "different" views on certain functionality, consider using different namespaces to express these different "views".

Answer (score 1):

`#include` directly inserts the file contents at the spot. So it depends on the contents of the header, but generally the answer is no. If it's a C header surrounding the inclusion with a namespace might work, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

`#include` is resolved during compilation, you can't change it in the code. But you can use preprocessor directives to control which files are included :

```
#if defined(A) && A > 3
#include 'somefile.h'
#else
#include 'someotherfile.h'
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution to your question (and the correct way to organize your source code) is to create a separate `.c` file for each function or group of related functions. For each `.c` file you also write a `.h` file that contains the declarations of the elements (types, constants, variables, functions) from the `.c` file that are published by that file.

The variables declared in the `.h` file need to be prefixed with the `extern` keyword (to let the compiler know they reside in a different `.c` file).

Then, let each `.c` file include only the `.h` files it needs (those that declare the functions/types/variables that are used in this `.c` file).

#### Example

File `firstInstructionSet.h`

```
typedef int number;

void registerObject();
```

File `firstInstructionSet.c`

```
void registerObject()
{
   /* code to register the object here */
}
```

File `oneDirective.h`

```
void functionOneDirective();
```

File `oneDirective.c`

```
#include "firstInstructionSet.h"

void functionOneDirective()
{
    registerObject();

    // cannot access instantiate() because
    // the symbol 'instantiate' is not known in this file
}
```

File `secondDirective.h`

```
extern int secondVar;

void functionSecondDirective();
```

File `secondDirective.c`

```
#include "secondInstructionSet.h"

int secondVar = 0;

void functionSecondDirective()
{
    instantiate();

    // cannot access registerObject() because
    // the symbol 'registerObject' is not known in this file
}
```

File `secondInstructionSet.h`

```
void instantiate();
```

File `secondInstructionSet.c`

```
void instantiate()
{
    /* code to instantiate here */
}
```

File `main.c`

```
#include "oneDirective.h"
#include "secondDirective.h"

void main()
{
    // cannot access instantiate() && registerObject()
    // because these symbols are not known in this file.

    // but can access functionOneDirective() and functionSecondDirective()
    // because the files that declare them are included (i.e. these
    // symbols are known at this point
    // it also can access variable "secondVar" and type "number"
}
```